# How to scrape the element with class having space in between using xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I was trying to scrape (https://www.zomato.com/pune/great-food-no-bull) title but I don't know how to scrape or find a element using xpath because of space in between T know how we can do this in css
The class name is:

```
sc-bwvMdh inVxXp
```

and I'm trying this

```
 div[@class="sc-bwvMdh inVxXp"]
```

please tell me how to do this

Comment: You need double slash `//div[@class="sc-bwvMdh inVxXp"]`

Comment: ohh yes , i forgot

Comment: What tittle element(s) are you trying to scrape? I see nothing matching XPath / classes you mentioned here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Full-xPath instead

like

```
element = find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]')
element.click()
```

for getting full xpath right click on the element on the dev tool and select copy > full xpath

[image: img]

if that doesn't work use XPath only like

```
element = find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div/section[1]/div/div[1]')
element.click()
```

or

```
element = find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.sc-1mo3ldo-0.sc-gGviUQ.dQbRoA > div > section.sc-bryTEL.oRXSB > div > div:nth-child(1)')
element.click()
```

there are other solutions but I think one of the above methods should do the work

getting css selector and xpath is the same as the picture
also, check if CSS classes are not auto-generated

Comment: thanks for participating but this will not work for all the elements